# How can I create 2+ HBase tables?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to create 2 HBase tables, but am running into some issues. Here is what I have so far. The tables are not being created correctly. The only tutorials and help I can find online are around creating ONE HBase table and not 2+ HBase tables.

Updates:

- I'm using HortonWorks Sandbox HDP 2.3.2.
- I'm not sure how I can create 2 tables without calling the Table Descriptor table twice to create both the holiday table and the group table
- The tutorial I'm using is: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hbase/hbase_create_table.htm

  public class TableCreation{

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
      HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(config);

      HTableDescriptor tableDescriptor = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf("holidays"));

      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("observed"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("date"));

      admin.createTable(tableDescriptor);

      HTableDescriptor tableDescriptor = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf("group"));

      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("type"));
      tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("size"));
      admin.createTable(tableDescriptor);
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: which version of hbase client api are you using? I can see few issues in the code (config, admin and tableDescriptor are declared twice). I wonder if your issue comes from here before looking further.
Also, some of the api are becoming deprecated, and you need may be to update your code.

Comment: Also what error are you getting?

Comment: I have listed the updates above:
1. I'm using HortonWorks Sandbox HDP 2.3.2. 
2. I'm not sure how I can create 2 tables without calling the Table Descriptor table twice to create both the holiday table and the group table
3. The tutorial I'm using is: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hbase/hbase_create_table.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to write some code that works and properly inserts 2 tables with columns. I am using Cloudera CDH5 Hadoop distribution.

This is a sample class that creates a table with column families:

```
 public class HBaseOps {

    public static void createTable(Connection conn, String tableName, String... families) throws IOException {

        Admin admin = conn.getAdmin();
        HTableDescriptor tableDescriptor = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf(tableName));

        for(String family : families) {
            tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(family));
        }
        admin.createTable(tableDescriptor);
    }
}
```

You can call the code above to create the tables:

```
    //Connect to hbase
    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);

    //Create table
    final String TABLE1 = "table1";
    final String FAMILY1 = "family1";
    final String FAMILY2 = "family2";
    HBaseOps.createTable(connection, TABLE1, FAMILY1, FAMILY2);

    //Create table
    final String TABLE2 = "table2";
    final String FAMILY3 = "family3";
    final String FAMILY4 = "family4";
    HBaseOps.createTable(connection, TABLE2, FAMILY3, FAMILY4);
```

You can find the full sample at my github:
[Full Code on Github](https://github.com/hichem/hadoop-samples/tree/master/hbase-sample)
I tested with hbase shell and the tables are properly created.